# How do I create and route a fake audio output to a real one?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, audio-output

I have a program that claims the default audio device in exclusive mode. This is not changable and it seems to not output any sound if I disallow that in sound settings.

So i figured the only way to fix this would be to somehow give it a fake audio output to claim, which routes to my headphones' audio output device, so that I can listen to other stuff while using the program. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1539069/how-to-use-multiple-audio-devices-as-a-surround/1539074#1539074) should help.

Just rout one of the virtual speakers to real output.